# Making an API Call with Swift

Tags: swift, api

I am trying to make an API GET call from my iOS App using swift and the error I am getting (i am testing this on a local server) is the following:

> [07/Sep/2015 18:04:26]"GET /user_management/api/v1/user/ HTTP/1.1" 401
>   0

Here is the code:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        var url : String = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_management/api/v1/user/"
        var request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()
        request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response:NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            var error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
            let jsonResult: NSArray! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSArray

            if (jsonResult != nil) {
                // process jsonResult

                println("success")


            } else {
                // couldn't load JSON, look at error

                println("fail")
            }

        })

        return true
    }
```

The console keeps printing out "fail".

Comment: HTTP 401 means Unauthorized. So I would start with that. There may be more details in the error variable or on the server.

Comment: As MirekE commented its a authentication error. Supply valid credentials or check the server side handling

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just `println("fail")` at least do `println("\(error.localizedDescription())")`

What it will tell you though is that the call is not authorized (that's what HTTP code 401 means, any time you get a failing result with an HTTP code try googling "**http code 401**")  You need to figure out how to pass in authentication first, or properly respond to the authentication challenge.